# DTE.ExecuteCommand and wait

Tags: c#, visual-studio, automation, macros, envdte

I would like use macros for publishing my webapplication project. The little problem is, DTE.ExecuteCommand run asynchronously, and I need to wait until the command is done.

Example:

```
    DTE.Windows.Item(Constants.vsWindowKindSolutionExplorer).Activate()
    DTE.ActiveWindow.Object.GetItem("04 - Products\04 - Products.WSS").Select(vsUISelectionType.vsUISelectionTypeSelect)
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("ClassViewContextMenus.ClassViewProject.Publish")
    '// now I want copy (and overwrite) some files, but AFTER the publish
```

Is there some synchronization object or information about state of executed command?

Comment: I'm also looking for an answer to this. I'd like to be able to run a series of ExecuteCommand statements in a macro, but synchronously.

Comment: Unfortunately I stil don't know a solution :(

Answer (score 5):

If you're still looking for an answer to this one, try this.

Tie into the publish events and on a successful push call your external command.  I'm doing a similar thing with building the solution and then firing the MSpec test runner ([blog post](http://kylefinley.net/archive/2009/10/05/1337.aspx)).

To do this you need to add in a hook for PublishEvents_OnPublishDone.  Do this by going to the EnvironmentEvents Module and addin the following:

```
<System.contextStaticAttribute()> Public WithEvents PublishEvents As EnvDTE80.PublishEvents

Private Sub PublishEvents_OnPublishDone(ByVal Success As Boolean) Handles PublishEvents.OnPublishDone
    'call custom module sub here.
End Sub
```

If you only want to run the external command sometimes do something like this.  Create your macro like this:

```
Public runExternalCommandOnComplete As Boolean = False

Sub PublishAndRunExternalCommand()

    DTE.Windows.Item(Constants.vsWindowKindSolutionExplorer).Activate()
    DTE.ActiveWindow.Object.GetItem("04 - Products\04 - Products.WSS").Select(vsUISelectionType.vsUISelectionTypeSelect)
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("ClassViewContextMenus.ClassViewProject.Publish")

    runExternalCommandOnComplete = True

End Sub
```

Then in EnvironmentEvents add this:  (Note: CustomMacros is the name of the module where you put the code above)

```
<System.contextStaticAttribute()> Public WithEvents PublishEvents As EnvDTE80.PublishEvents

Private Sub PublishEvents_OnPublishDone(ByVal Success As Boolean) Handles PublishEvents.OnPublishDone
   CustomMacros.runExternalCommandOnComplete = False
   'Where ExternalCommand1 matches the command you want to run
   DTE.ExecuteCommand("Tools.ExternalCommand1")  
End Sub
```

That should do it.

Comment: Iw works for publish (+1), but it does not solve the other commands (I'm not sure, there is a solution).

However, thans :)

Comment: You could go ghetto with your other one and create some sort of file based mechanism for determining what to do.  Basically call your external command using a batch file that does run synchronously and at the end drops a temp file somewhere.  Back in VS create a sub that then watches for that file to exist.  Once it does go ahead and fire off your other macro stuff and then clean up the file.

Maybe a bit much but could work.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can compile single file, and then link whole solution for example:

```
Dim WithEvents t As Timers.Timer

Sub test()
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("Build.Compile")
    t = New Timers.Timer
    t.Interval = 0.05
    t.Start()
End Sub

Sub t_Elapsed(ByVal ee As Object, ByVal dd As Timers.ElapsedEventArgs) Handles t.Elapsed

    If DTE.Solution.SolutionBuild.BuildState <> vsBuildState.vsBuildStateInProgress Then
        t.Stop()
        DTE.ExecuteCommand("Build.Link")
    End If

End Sub
```