# Wait for Visual Studio DTE ExecuteCommand to finish

Tags: visual-studio, envdte

Using the Visual Studio DTE, I can execute commands with the ExecuteCommand method. However, they are executed asynchronously. I would like to wait until for the ExecuteCommand method to finish before the next method is called. Is there a way to call ExecuteCommand syncronously?

Comment: Similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000137/dte-executecommand-and-wait

Comment: Which command in particular? Not all commands are 'asynchronous'. Try, for example raising "File.NewProject", and you'll be "blocked" until the dialog is dismissed.