# Programmatically publish web application

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vsx, envdte

I'm trying to write a visual studio extension that allows me to publish multiple web applications in a solution, similar to using the one-click publish feature on all the projects.

```
DTE2 service = (DTE2)this.GetService(typeof(DTE));
Projects projects = service.Solution.Projects;
SolutionBuild2 build = (SolutionBuild2)service.Solution.SolutionBuild;

foreach (Project project in projects)
{
   build.PublishProject("Release", project.UniqueName, true);
}
```

When I try to run this code, the only result in the output window is this:

```
Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

... which doesn't tell me much.  Is there a way to find out what's going wrong?

I also see there an interface [IVsPublishableProjectCfg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivspublishableprojectcfg%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), but there doesn't seem to be any examples of how to use it.

Is there another way to programmatically publish web applications to a certain directory, similar to how the one-click publish feature works?

Comment: It might help if you told us which line throws the exception

Comment: have you tried stepping through using the debugger?

Comment: It doesn't throw an exception.  It just writes out that error message to the output window when I try to use the extension in the experimental Visual Studio.   I can successfully step through all the lines without it throwing any kind of exception.

Comment: and when you step through does it actually publish any of the projects?

Comment: No, it doesn't.  The output window in the experimental Visual Studio contains the error message and no projects have been published.

Comment: @nivlam did you succeed eventually?

Answer (score 0):

An alternate way to do this is to simulate clicking of the right-click "Publish" context menu item in Solution explorer, as in this similar question:
[DTE.ExecuteCommand and wait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000137/dte-executecommand-and-wait)

Note that, as this is an asynchronous command, you will need to build in logic to tap into the post-publish events to iterate over your collection of projects (some detail on this is shown in one of the included answers).

Answer (score 0):

Use the msbuild.exe executable (which is how you're building anyway), pass your sln file as the project argument, and target the "Publish" target.

```
msbuild SlnFolders.sln /t:Publish
```

You can declare some properties in the command line or you can declare them statically using your own .targets file; reference this .targets file in your .csproj.

```
<Import Project="MyPublishCustomizations.targets" />
```

The contents of the .targets file might look like this:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <Target Name="Publish">
    </Target>
    <!-- or .. -->
    <Target Name="CustomPublish" BeforeTargets="Publish">
    </Target>
</Project>
```

.. the `<Target ..>` XML could then have in it ..

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <MyCustomPath>\\our_server\our_share</MyCustomPath>
</PropertyGroup>
<Copy SourceFiles="$(OutDir)\*" DestinationFiles="$(MyCustomPath)" />
```

You can then define any other MSBuild tasks, even shell commands with `<Exec ..>`.

More generally on MSBuild here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd393573.aspx

Also if you insist on writing your publish logic in C#, you might consider the path described above and define a custom *MSBuild task*, i.e.

```
<ExecuteMyCustomTaskDefinedInCSharp ParameterA="Hello" ParameterB="World" />
```

Learn how [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9883dzc.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it boils down to calling msbuild somehow like this:

```
msbuild.exe "MyProject.csproj" /p:PublishProfile="MyPublishProfile.pubxml" /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:VisualStudioVersion="14.0"
```

I have written a PowerShell cmdlet for this, which I can call from the NuGet package manager console.

Comment: Could you give an example on how to run this command programmatically from C# using the cmdlet you specified?

Comment: @Jacob As I mentioned, I created that cmdlet for calling msbuild from the *console*. If you want to call msbuild from C# it would probably be something like `Process.Start("msbuild.exe", "MyProject.csproj /p:PublishProfile=..."`